# How can I optimize a join with multi-table sort in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, query-optimization

How can I optimize the following query?

```
   SELECT TOP 50 *
     FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id 
 ORDER BY A.number, B.name DESC
```

I created a non-clustered index on (A.number asc, A.creation_date desc), which includes all columns from A, and another non-clustered index on B.origination_date desc, which includes all columns from B (except text columns). Neither of these indices are used, according to the actual execution plan from SQL Server Management Studio.

The thing that seems to be causing the performance hit is the B.origination_date sort. When I examine the actual execution plan in SQL Server Management Studio, I see that "Top N Sort" on these three fields takes up 91% of the execution time. If I drop off the sort on B.origination_date, the query completes almost instantaneously, using the index on A.

**Edit:**
Updated the query to provide a better, simpler example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sorting on columns from two different tables, SQL Server has to join the tables and then do the sort.  Once the tables are joined, the indexes on the individual tables are no help to the sort.  An indexed view might be your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess **A.number like '%%'** is your problem. What is this intended to do? You should not be using a like with a wildcard as the first character if you want to use the indexes. As this stands it appears to be filtering for nothing as tere is nothing between the wildcards.

Comment: The intent is to return all records. As I mentioned, the bulk of the execution time is spent in the sort. Removing the where clause doesn't have an impact; I'll edit the question above and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Without hands-on access, it’s hard to come up with hard and fast solutions. Some ideas and suggestions:

Without the join on table B, all SQL has to do (with the index on A.Number) is walk through until it finds the first 50 rows that match your pattern. If the values of  “Number” are relatively unique (not many duplicates [this is cardinality]), there’s little value in having Creation_Date in the index as well.

Why the left outer join into B? Is it one to [zero or one], or one to [zero or many]? If the cardinality is low (many duplicates in A) then the join is required to clearly find the “first 50”, otherwise one would think the join wouldn’t impact performance beyond the need to perform the join). I can’t see any index on B (besides on column id) making any difference here. Um, you do have an index on B.Id, right? If not, that could slow things down tremendously (presuming that B has a significant number of rows, of course).

For more sepcifics, I’d want to review the cardinality of the join and order by columns, and look very closely at the execution plan of the “with join” query.

---

Addenda

If A has low cardinality (many duplicates), then the query optimizer may "think" that it will have to use a lot B.Id to resolve ordering (which must be done to find the Top 50). This might explain why it does what it does.

If they will produce 100% equivalent results, I would recommend replacing the LEFT join with an INNER join. In general, query plans can become much simpler when more restrictive join conditions are in place.

Comment: Good questions, thanks. The relation is many-to-one (many A's to one B), and an INNER JOIN would also work correctly. I updated the example to eliminate the date field, which, you're right, isn't very useful. What I really want is to sort by A.number, B.name; the revised query above exhibits the same problem. The query uses B's clustered primary key, and an index scan on my new index for A. What I don't understand is why the query takes so much time doing another sort after joining A and B; it seems like since the index for A is sorted, it should (intuitively) have to do less work.

Comment: I should also mention that multiple records can have the same A.number; hence the use of B to differentiate them, as a secondary sort.